# At what age does Pon Farr start?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

On the episode "Amok Time" Spock explains the Pon Farr happens every seven years. Does that mean they "Pon Farr" when they're seven and fourteen!?

Comment: When does Vulcan puberty start?

Comment: @Mithrandir I would guess around the same time human puberty starts based on Spock enduring Pon Farr on the Genesis planet when he was biologically 16 or 17

Comment: Rp1209 - Technically I should point out that according to Star Trek Script Search Spock doesn't say Pon Farr happens every 7 years in "Amok Time".  Those statements are in "The Cloud Minders" and Star Trek III: The Search For Spock.  http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/?page=results&query=(%7Bseries%7Ctos,tas,%7D)%20and%20(%7Bline%7Cseven%20years,%7D)

Comment: Spock and T'Pring were bonded when age seven.  This might suggest that possible ages for future Pon Farrs would be 14, 21, 28, 35 and 42, etc. suggesting that Spock could have been 28, 35, or 42 in "Amok Time".   If Spock had his first Pon Farr aged 17 like his rejuvenated self, later Pon Farrs would be at ages 24, 31, 38, etc., suggesting Spock may have been 31 or 38 in "Amok Time".  If Spock's first Pon Farr was in "Amok Time" his later ones would be in 7 year intervals after his age - whatever it was - in "Amok Time".

Answer (score 6):

No. It seems to start sometime after the onset of puberty.

In that scene, Spock is in his mid to late teens and is experiencing what appears to be his first Pon Farr based on Saavik's comment "so, it has come"

Comment: You might also want to address that T'Pol doesn't go through her first Pon Farr until she's 66 years of age, and then only because of an infection

Comment: Video link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

The onset of Pon Farr for the regenerated Spock in *Star Trek III* occurred when the character was played by Stephen Manley, who was credited as "Spock, Age 17."  So, for Spock, it was definitely 17, although it probably varies a bit from individual to individual.

Answer (score 0):

Vorik on Star Trek Voyager looks as though he is about 21 to 28 years old. They tell us that Volcans go through the pon farr every 7 years of their adult life. The pon farr should start at the end of puberty. I would say the first pon farr would start at age 21.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Crefits of Star Trek the search for Spock the role of Spock was 25 years old when Saavik was present during the resurgence of his pon far.

Comment: Hi there and welcome! It's not quite clear to me what your source is on this. Could you expand your answer at all, to add more information?